# sql server back up file before and after restore

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a sql server database back up file (backed up from  R2 version). The backup file was originally 700 MB. But I droped some tables and when I backed it up again, It came to almost 4 MB.

Unfortuneatly when I restore it to another SQL server instance (R2 again) the Data base size grows to almost 700 MB again.

Would you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but may be [shrink database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189035.aspx) will help you.